# Construct DataFrame from scraped data using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem with constructing csv type data file from scraped data. I have managed to scrape the data from the table but when it comes to writing it I can't do that for days. I am using items and trying to write it to pandas data frame. I am using items list.

```
import scrapy
from wiki.items import WikiItem
import pandas as pd

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "wiki"
start_urls = ['https://datatables.net/']

def parse(self, response):

    items = {'Name':[], 'Position':[], 'Office':[], 'Age':[],
        'Start_Date':[],'Salary':[]}

    trs = response.xpath('//table[@id="example"]//tr')
    name = WikiItem()
    pos = WikiItem()
    office = WikiItem()
    age = WikiItem()
    start_data = WikiItem()
    salary = WikiItem()

    name['name'] = trs.xpath('//td[1]//text()').extract()
    pos['position'] = trs.xpath('//td[2]//text()').extract()
    office['office'] = trs.xpath('//td[3]//text()').extract()
    age['age'] = trs.xpath('//td[4]//text()').extract()
    start_data['start_data'] = trs.xpath('//td[5]//text()').extract()
    salary['salary'] = trs.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract()

    items['Name'].append(name)
    items['Position'].append(pos)
    items['Office'].append(office)
    items['Age'].append(age)
    items['Start_Date'].append(start_data)
    items['Salary'].append(salary)

    x = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Name','Position','Office','Age',
        'Start_Date','Salary'])

    yield x.to_csv("r",sep=",")
```

From this code what I get is like this ;

```
,Name,Position,Office,Age,Start_Date,Salary
0,"{'name': [u'Tiger Nixon',
      u'Garrett Winters',
      u'Ashton Cox',
      u'Cedric Kelly',
      u'Airi Satou',
      u'Brielle Williamson',
      u'Herrod Chandler',
```

I am getting the names column but I get it 59 times.For instance I have the first row, 'Tiger Nixon' 59 times. I get 59 times position column also and so on. And the scraped data is not in good shape also. I am new to scrapy and open to any help or suggestions. Thanks in advance!

EDIT : My items.py is like this;

```
import scrapy


class WikiItem(scrapy.Item):


name = scrapy.Field()
position = scrapy.Field()
office = scrapy.Field()
age = scrapy.Field()
start_data = scrapy.Field()
salary = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I can't comment and I can't test your code because I don't have the definition of WikiItem. But let iterate over this response, ok?
Can you check what do you get with this code?

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "wiki"
    start_urls = ['https://datatables.net/']

    def parse(self, response):

        trs = response.xpath('//table[@id="example"]//tr')

        if trs:
            items = []
            for tr in trs:
                print tr.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
                item = {
                    "Name": tr.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract(),
                    "Position": tr.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract(),
                    "Office": tr.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract(),
                    "Age": tr.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract(),
                    "Start_Date": tr.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract(),
                    "Salary": tr.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract()
                }
                items.append(item)


            x = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Name','Position','Office','Age',
                'Start_Date','Salary'])

            yield x.to_csv("r",sep=",")
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question, added the items.py. When I tried your code, I got 59 row. Each row has whole names, positions, office, age, start_date, and salary information and each row is the same. I think my problem comes from items.py.

Comment: Test the new version and let me know if its better.

Comment: It is working! Thanks a lot. I suppose the problem was with the usage of dictionary.

Comment: Yes. And also check the little change on the elements xpath from `//td[1]//text()` to `td[1]//text()` . I removed the `//` to make this xpath relative to the `tr` and not to the entire document ;) If it's running can you vote the response? ;)
Best regards.

Comment: I will when I get 15 reputation! Best!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly pertaining to the use-case as posed by the question, but I feel it's relevant to the question's title: **how to return pd DataFrame object in scrapy Spider**?

#### Context:

If you are trying to export a `pd.DataFrame` object in a scrapy spider, if you directly state `yield df`, for example:

```py
import scrapy 
import json
import pandas as pd 

class Spider(scrapy.Spider): 
   start_urls = ['mywebsite.com'] 

   def parse(self, response):
       #Let us assume mywebsite.com contains a script tag with JSON data rendered serverside
       script = response.xpath('//script[@id="windowData"]/text()').extract_first()
      
       data = json.loads(script)

       #Construct dataframe from dictionary
       df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['anInterestingPieceOfData'])
 
       yield df
```

This will return an error that the thing you are trying to yield is not a `Request, BaseItem, dict or None`, instead it is a `DataFrame`.

#### Solution

So the question becomes, how can I convert the `DataFrame` object into a dict of some sort? This doesn't concern your feed export format (if the spider is outputting a CSV or JSON or whatever).

You could use anything from pandas `to_csv`, `to_json`, but I find that a flexible option is to use `to_dict`, such as using the `yield from` syntax:

```
yield from self.df.to_dict(orient="records")
```